# What parametrization should I use for this double integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-domain

I have this domain:
$$D = \{ (x,y) | y \ge0, y \le x\le 1\}, f = \sqrt{4x^2-y^2}$$ 
I need to evaluate the double integral on this domain. I tried using cartesian coordinates, but after computing the first integral I got a too diffcult one which I couldn't solve.

BTW, in cartesian coordinates I used $0 \le y \le 1$ and $ y \le x \le 1$.
Can I use polar coordinates. If so, how? Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: What does $f$ look like?

Comment: the region is a triangle

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try integrating over $y$ first.

Comment: I did that taking $x$ between 0 and 1 and y between 0 and x. But it doesn't work. I integrated the first integral by parts. And eventually reached to a difficult logarithm...

Comment: You should get $$\int_0^x \sqrt{4 x^2 - y^2}\; dy = \left. \frac{y \sqrt{4 x^2 - y^2}}{2} + 2 x^2 \arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{4x^2-y^2}}\right) \right|_{y=0}^x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x^2 + \frac{\pi}{3} x^2$$

Comment: I don't think your solution is right. This is what I've got:
$\int_0^x \sqrt{4x^2-y^2}dy = y\sqrt{4x^2-y^2}-\int_0^x y \dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{4x^2-y^2}}dy$

Comment: And now you add and substract $4x^2$ obtaining at first the integral from which you've left and then a logarithm (i.e. $\ln(x+\sqrt{4x^2-y^2})$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use substitution \begin{align} u &= 2x - y, \\ v& = 2x + y. \end{align}